# Categorizing data based on value of interger using Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have these two variables:

```
instance = [0.45,6.54,19.0,3.34,2.34]
distance_tolerance = [5.00,10.00,20.00]
```

I like to sort each data in `instance` and categorize it based on their value that is fewer than each data in `distance_tolerance` and save it in a variable.

For example `0.45 < 5.00` then make a variable to save `0.45` and iterate for every data.

Expected result:

```
data5 = [0.45,3.34,2.34]
data10 = [0.45,6.54,3.34,2,34]
data20 = [0.45,6.54,19.0,3.34,2.34]
```

I need to do looping for this task since the real data is large.

What is the best way to perform this task? thanks

Comment: Are you open to using NumPy for the performance part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply  iterative through and append the values of `instance` which are lower than the value of `distance_tolerance` that your on.

So for some element in `distance_tolerance` you could have a function called `itemsLowerThan(value)` which will return an array of the elements in `instance` that are lower than the value you pass.

For example:

```
instance = [0.45,6.54,19.0,3.34,2.34]
distance_tolerance = [5.00,10.00,20.00]

def itemsLowerThan(value):
  arr = []
  for item in instance:
    if (item < value):
      arr.append(item)
  return arr

for tolerance in distance_tolerance:
  print(itemsLowerThan(tolerance))
```

Would give the output:

```
[0.45, 3.34, 2.34]
[0.45, 6.54, 3.34, 2.34]
[0.45, 6.54, 19.0, 3.34, 2.34]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
[[i for i in instance if i < tolerance] for tolerance in distance_tolerance]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[
    [0.45, 3.34, 2.34],
    [0.45, 6.54, 3.34, 2,34],
    [0.45, 6.54, 19.0, 3.34, 2.34],
]
```